# split json into carousel cards

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, chunks

I get the results from a JSON file and I want to display it in carousel,
how can I do it?

Here is the code:

```
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    if (res.statusCode !== 201) {
        session.send("Sorry, service is not reachable at the moment, please try again later");
    }
    //session.send(res.statusCode.toString());
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);

        var json = chunk.toString();
        var graph = JSON.parse(json);
        var attachmentList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < graph.clauses.length; i++) {
            var obj = graph.clauses[i];
            console.log(obj);
            var clause_id;
            var clause_text;

            for (var key in obj) {
                clause_id = key;
                clause_text = obj[key].toString();
                // session.send(clause_id+"<br>"+clause_text);
            }

            let card = new botbuilder_1.HeroCard(session)
                .title(clause_id)
                .subtitle(clause_text)
                .buttons([botbuilder_1.CardAction.imBack(session, 'Mark as Relevant', 'Mark as Relevant')]);

            let msg = new botbuilder_1.Message(session);
            msg.attachmentLayout(botbuilder_1.AttachmentLayout.carousel);
            msg.attachments([card]);
            session.send(msg);

            // session.endDialog(msg); 
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the screenshot of the results:

[image]

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You're getting that JSON in the result of an HTTP request and you want to convert each object in the clauses array into a card and then display all those cards in a carousel. Is that correct?

Comment: Please provide the code you're using to generate the carousel so that we can see what you've tried and what you need help with.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I had success to retrieve from JSON , now how can I combine all the HeroCard as carousel? I had update with screenshot and source code

Comment: var json=chunk.toString(); var graph = JSON.parse(json); How are you assuming your chunk is a valid json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a message on each iteration of the for loop, and each message only has one attachment. Try sending one message after the for loop and give that message the whole list of attachments.

```
var attachmentList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < graph.clauses.length; i++) {
    var obj = graph.clauses[i];
    console.log(obj);
    var clause_id;
    var clause_text;
    for (var key in obj) {
        clause_id = key;
        clause_text = obj[key].toString();
        // session.send(clause_id+"<br>"+clause_text);
    }
    let card = new botbuilder_1.HeroCard(session)
        .title(clause_id)
        .subtitle(clause_text)
        .buttons([botbuilder_1.CardAction.imBack(session, 'Mark as Relevant', 'Mark as Relevant')]);

    attachmentList.push(card);
}

let msg = new botbuilder_1.Message(session);
msg.attachmentLayout(botbuilder_1.AttachmentLayout.carousel);
msg.attachments(attachmentList);
session.send(msg);
```